# Merge two excel files (with the condition)

Tags: vba

I have a form in access in which i have two text boxes which accepts two excel files with a button click.
now when i click generate button an output excel file has to be generated or created based on the following conditions

In one excel file i have these data :

```
id      code    country count
t100    gb123   india   3123
t100    gh125   UK      1258
t123    ytr15   USA     1111
t123    gb123   Germany 100
t145    gh575   india   99
t458    yt777   USA     90
```

In another excel file i have these data

```
country location
India   delhi
UK      london
USA     wallstreet
Germany frankfurt
```

The rows can be more than what i mentioned here ... now i want to merge them
according to the country. In book1 excel file for example wherever you find country india the location
field delhi has to be inserted right beside the country field and it has to be done for each and every country which i mentioned in book2 excel file
and the output file has to be sorted according to the count at last.

For example the output file should like this

```
id     code  country count Location
t100   gb123 india   3123  delhi
t100   gh125 UK      1258  london
t123   ytr15 USA     1111  wallstreet
t123   gb123 Germany  100  frankfrt
t145   gh575 india     99  delhi
t458   yt777 USA       90  wallstreet
```

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're describing between "accepting" and "generating" the Excel files is best handled in Access as a query joining two tables of data on the country field.

Not knowing more about your project or what you mean by "accept", I'd recommend either linking the Excel files as external data so that they can be used directly as tables, or importing their contents in tables in Access, then constructing the query to join the data as you described. The results of the query can then be exported back to Excel.

To provide a more specific answer, I'd need more details of how you're looking to handle the Excel import/export.